# What is the difference between the DependencyInjection and without DependencyInjection example?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I came across an example regarding DI and without DI. But was not really able to understand how it is different. May be if the complete code along with the values might be able to show the difference explicitly. Unfortunately i am not sure how to make those examples more sensible or make the difference clearly visible. Can someone provide appropriate missing code to make it more sensible.Screenshot of the example attached.
[image]

How one is forced and the other is not?

Answer (score 0):

**DI:**
It means that if you want/need to, you can create an `Employee` class and *inject* an `Address` object while doing so thus being able to use *any* Address for your Employee and not having to worry about that field (as in you don't care which Address is, it will be taken care of by someone that will use this Employee class).

So basically:

```
// constructing Employees from some other class

    Employee spanishEmployee = new Employee(spanishAddress);
    Employee russianEmployee = new Employee(russianAddress);
```

And you decouple the Address from the Employee.

**Without DI:**
This first example you see shows that when you create your Employee object, you also need to *worry* about the Address field because your Employee has it as a *dependency* which you cannot choose dynamically when creating an Employee